# How to serialize a sub type as if it is the super type with jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2

So I'm trying to use jackson to serialize my session and I'm using jpa and gauva.

I'm seeing errors like:

```
Could not read JSON: The class with org.apache.openjpa.util.java$util$Date$proxy and name of org.apache.openjpa.util.java$util$Date$proxy is not whitelisted
```

So in other words, the date type that is serialized is the sub type.

Now what I'd like to do is to serialize the data type as the Date type and not the specific type so that I can simplify serialization and especially simplify deserialization.

I'm hoping there's a way to simply add mappings, i.e. if you find X type then serialize it as Y type.

Comment: **I'm hoping there's a way to simply add mappings... i.e. if you find X type then serialize it as Y type.** There is an annotation `@JsonProperty` that tells jackson to interpret some value as described in that annotation. For example: `@JsonProperty("value1") String someValue;`

Comment: I think what you need is a custom serializer, here you can find an example: https://dzone.com/articles/how-serialize-javautildate

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments.

So what I didn't realize is that when customising serialization with a mixin you need to add the mixin on the declared type and not on the actual type. I needed to override the default config as the default config was including the type (org.apache.openjpa.util.java$util$Date$proxy) and I added a mixin for this type. But what I actually need to do is add a mixing for java.util.Date because this is the declared type.

So now by adding the mixin:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NONE)
public static class DateMixin {

}
```

By doing

```
context.setMixInAnnotations(Date.class, DateMixin.class);
```

and not:

```
context.setMixInAnnotations(org.apache.openjpa.util.java$util$Date$proxy.class, DateMixin.class);
```

I get my expected behaviour.

It was serializing my dates as

> "date":["org.apache.openjpa.util.java$util$Date$proxy",1571822501152]}

and now with the mixin added I get:

> "date":1571822501152

Which is what I'm looking for.